# Is it possible to use the R package lattice to auto-generate plots by date?

Tags: r, datetime, lattice

I have a data frame where the two columns of interest are a list of measurements (as integers) and the date/time when the measurement was taken (as POSIXct). When I plot the entire set, it's difficult to see any detail since the data were taken every five minutes and the data span ~2 months. I was hoping that I could use lattice to generate a plot of each day on its own without having to specify the xmin/xmax 60 times. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, use a loop or apply

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```r
# Generate some fake data
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(500), 
                  y = rnorm(500), 
                  date = sample(Sys.Date()+1:20, 500, replace=TRUE))
library(lattice)
xyplot(y ~ x | date, data=dat)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>